# Passing conditional function argument ('&') to a custom angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom angular directive that accepts two function parameters, addElement and removeElement:

```
.directive('myDirective', ['$window', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                addElement: '&',
                removeElement: '&'
            },
            templateUrl: window.root + 'myDirectiveHtml.html'
        };
    }])
```

I cannot figure out how to set these two attributes conditionally outside the directive and how to conditionally use these two function parameters inside the directive. I would like to be able to pass either a function or 'null' into the directive and based on that, code proper logic inside.

Currently I have two more parameters (not listed in above code) in my directive, enableAdd and enableRemove. I would like to remove these two attributes and determine them based on the logic explained above.

From the outside, currently, the directive is instantiated like this:

```
<myDirective add-element="addElementFunc()"
             remove-element="removeElement()"
             enable-remove="{{ 1===1 ? 'true' : 'false' }}"
             enable-add="{{ 1===1 ? 'true' : 'false' }}" />
```

Inside my directive, currently, I use the the enable/disable properties like this:

```
<div ng-show="enableAdd" ng-click="addElement()">Add</div>
<div ng-show="enableRemove" ng-click="removeElement()">Add</div>
```

So basically my question is how to remove enableAdd/enableRemove attributes and just code that logic based on whether addElement/removeElement is null or function.

Comment: You can just do: `ng-show="addEelment"`, and that will work, since if nothing is passed in the `addElement` function is undefined and the `ng-show` evaluates to false....

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand: That is one part. What about declaring that condition to set the add-element attribute on the directive?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this,
create two boolean values in parent controller and then condition pass of function into directive by them. for example:

parent controller:

```
$scope.triggerAdd = false;
$scope.triggerRmove = true;
```

parent html:

```
  <myDirective add-element="triggerAdd ? addElementFunc() : false"
                 remove-element="triggerRmove ? removeElement(): false"
                 enable-remove="{{ 1===1 ? 'true' : 'false' }}"
                 enable-add="{{ 1===1 ? 'true' : 'false' }}" >
    </myDirective>
```